# Selenium vba cannot find element using id

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Im trying to use VBA and selenium to find an element using its id. Despite having the correct element id and the right code, When I run my code it always says can not find element id.

This is my code that I use to open the website then search for the element.

---

```
MyBrowser.Start baseUrl:="https://cibc.service-now.com/change_request.do?sysparm_query=%5EGOTOnumber%3D" & sTicket   

MyBrowser.Get "/"

Set SearchInput = MyBrowser.FindElementById("sys_readonly.change_request.start_date")***
```

and this is the html of the element I am trying to find on the page

```
"input style=";;" class="form-control disabled" id="sys_readonly.change_request.start_date" value="2021-10-14 00:00:01" readonly="readonly" aria-label="Planned Start Date"
```

If anyone can help out with how I can do retrieve the value of this element I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `id` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Comment: @cruisepandey , Yes I did check and it is unique. there is another match for it but it looks like this, which I don't think affect it.                                                                        <label for="sys_readonly.change_request.start_date" class="url  col-xs-12 col-md-1_5 col-lg-2 control-label" dir="ltr" style="width: 100%; text-align: left;"><span id="status.change_request.start_date" aria-label="Read only - cannot be modified" data-dynamic-title="Click to View Maintenance Calendar" mandatory="false" oclass="read_only" class="read_only "></span><a target="blank".....

Comment: The element could be hiding behind an iframe, check the html if there is one. If the website is publicly available, please give a valid URL so that we can test it.

Comment: @RaymondWu, it is not hidden behind an iframe and the page is private so I can not share the link.

Comment: @Ayman In that case, since you are using Selenium and it also means the browser needs time to load the content, have you tried delaying for few seconds (or however long it takes) before `FindElementById`? Set a breakpoint at that line and make the browser visible, when the code stops, wait for that element to appear visually then run the line.